# Spring Websocket TaskExecutor-beans displaces "applicationTaskExecutor"-bean

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 2.1.8 Application that uses `@Async`-Tasks. All `@Async`-Tasks used to be executed by an automatically configured `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`-bean named `applicationTaskExecutor`.

**What did I change?**
With `spring-boot-starter-websocket` in the class path and a `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` configuration the `applicationTaskExecutor`-bean  is gone and replaced by four beans with the names

- `clientInboundChannelExecutor`,
- `clientOutboundChannelExecutor`,
- `brokerChannelExecutor`,
- and `messageBrokerTaskScheduler`.

Spring logs to the console: `AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor : More than one TaskExecutor bean found within the context, and none is named 'taskExecutor'. Mark one of them as primary or name it 'taskExecutor' (possibly as an alias) in order to use it for async processing: [clientInboundChannelExecutor, clientOutboundChannelExecutor, brokerChannelExecutor, messageBrokerTaskScheduler]`

`@Async`-tasks are now executed by `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.

**Question**
Why can't all beans co-exist? Why won't Spring create a `applicationTaskExecutor`-bean when spring-websockets is configured?

Comment: The `applicationTaskExecutor` is only created if no other `TaskExecutor` is available. If there is it will not be created. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.java#L78.

Answer (score 0):

As @M. Deinum mentioned in the comments a `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` in `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.java` [0] results in the described behavior

I solved it by creating the bean by myself.

```
@ConditionalOnClass(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.class)
@Configuration
public class ApplicationTaskExecutorBeanConfig {

    @Lazy
    @Bean(name = {APPLICATION_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME, DEFAULT_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME})
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor(TaskExecutorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

First I tried to prefer the bean from `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.java` by annotating my bean factory method with

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = {APPLICATION_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME, DEFAULT_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME})
```

but it didn't worked because my bean factory method gets invoked earlier than the one in `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.java`.

[0] https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.java#L78

*Thanks to @M. Deinum for your comment.*